# Как рассчитать ECDSA для своего сервера?

Tags: linux, ssh, администрирование

При подключении к новому серверу по SSH выдаётся известное сообщение:

> The authenticity of host '' can't be established.
>
> ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Я привык при настройке нового сервера делать так. После того, как установлена операционная система делать подключение по ssh со своей рабочей станции и записывать себе ECDSA key fingerprint -- а потом уже его вписывать в реестр серверов (по сути это эксельный файл: как-то планировали перейти на SSHFP-записи в DNS, да ни nic.ru, ни masterhost.ru их не поддерживает, увы) и рассылать заинтересованным лицам.

Тем не менее, если я правильно понимаю, что чисто гипотетически существует некоторая малая вероятность, что я уже в этот момент подключаюсь не к своему серверу, который настраивал с консоли, а какому-то другому. И, по-хорошему, необходимо рассчитать это значение на консоли сервера и именно его сохранять в реестр.

Только как это сделать правильно? Я искал среди вопросов на en so и в интернете, но как правило этот момент обходится стороной, а всё сводится к вопросу "если пищит, что фингерпринт сервера поменялся -- просто удали старое закешированное значение в authorized_host".

Comment: А нельзя ли из консоли подключиться по SSH на localhost?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Формально -- думаю, что можно. В тех случаях, когда я подключался к серверам, то имена совпадали когда я подключался к servername, servername.domain и localhost, по IP и по IP-адресу второй сетевой карты -- но если вы хотите этот хак оформить ответом, то я плюсану... но не уверен, что поставлю галку. Хотелось бы какой-либо ссылки на документацию, чтобы подтвердить, что это не просто эмпирические наблюдения, но хорошие рекомендации по безопасности.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Плюс, у меня-то такой проблемы нет, все сервера давно в списке, но если бы у меня был старый сервер, для которого забыли записать в файл фингерпринт, то как его узнать? Выковырять из `~/.ssh/known_hosts` не выйдет, а удалить нужную строку из known_hosts не выйдет (не всегда выйдет), да даже если и выйдет -- то как-то костыльно это выглядит. Самое правильное видимо -- это зайти локально на сервер и рассчитать фингерпринт локально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `ECDSA key fingerprint is 00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f.`

приведённая строка похожа на md5-хэш ключа.

его можно получить так:

```
$ ssh-keygen -E md5 -l -f /путь/к/файлу/с/ключом
```

ключ может быть как секретным, так и публичным (значение будет одним и тем же, т.к. хэш вычисляется от одной и той же информации). хранятся они по умолчанию в каталоге `/etc/ssh`. файл с ключом, сгенерированным по [алгоритму ecdsa](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECDSA), как правило, содержит эти буквы в своём имени. т.е., может называться, к примеру, `ssh_host_ecdsa_key` (и `ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` для публичной части).

пример получения md5-хэша:

```
$ ssh-keygen -E md5 -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
256 MD5:db:e2:64:00:c8:24:2b:0a:3e:9b:e2:e8:5d:90:4e:3e root@host (ECDSA)
```

по умолчанию же нынче считается sha256-хэш:

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub 
256 SHA256:rQZP7aZXqJc2Qh4ZVYw8Jn5j+xUo/Qx7/WFEiOseztU root@host (ECDSA)
```

---

подробнее см. `$ man ssh-keygen` в вашей системе.

Comment: Для Centos7 получил отпечаток через `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` без ключа -E (такого нет) и по умолчанию считался именно вариант с md5.

Comment: @AK, да там явно довольно древний openssh.